# How To Rotate an Image using a StoryBoard

Tags: wpf, animation

I am trying to rotate an image and want to use a storyboard as in the next phases i need to add multiple animations running to time.

my code is inside a click event of a button as follows:

```
//start the animation
            DoubleAnimation animationRotation = new DoubleAnimation();
    
            animationRotation.From = -17;
            animationRotation.To = 17;
            animationRotation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(NumericDisplay.Milliseconds));
            animationRotation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            animationRotation.AccelerationRatio = 0.3;
            animationRotation.DecelerationRatio = 0.3;
            animationRotation.AutoReverse = true;
            
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animationRotation, Arm);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationRotation,
              new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)")); 

            storyboard.Children.Add(animationRotation);

            // Add the storyboard to the tracking collection.      
            //this.Stostoryboards.Add(bomb, storyboard);
            
            // Configure and start the storyboard.
            this.BeginStoryboard(storyboard);
```

the code compiles without warning yet the click event does not start the animation,

**EDIT**
One of the proposed answers asked me to check the XAML included a definition for rotatetransform ... the XAML below is what I am using

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="ImageBrush_Decrement" ImageSource="Images/pad-metronome-decrement-button.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="ImageBrush_Increment" ImageSource="Images/pad-metronome-increment-button.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="412">
    <Image x:Name="MetronomeWindowBackground" Height="140" Margin="237,1.5,231,0" Source="Images\pad-metronome-top-under-bg.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Image x:Name="Arm" Margin="506,17,493,0" Source="Images\pad-metronome-arm.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="326" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform/>
                
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image x:Name="MetronomeFlash" Height="209" Margin="104,0,96,0" Source="Images\pad-metronome-flash-top-landscape.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsHidden="True" />
    <Image x:Name="MetronomeBackground" Height="209" Source="Images\pad-metronome-top-bg-landscape.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="3,0,-3,0"/>
    <Image x:Name="MetronomeStartButton" Margin="379.5,100.5,373.5,0" Source="Images\pad-metronome-start-button-base.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="110" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Image x:Name="MetronomeTapPadLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="209" Margin="5,1.5,0,0" Source="Images\pad-metronome-tap-pad-left.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136"/>
    <Image x:Name="MetronomeTapPadRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="Images\pad-metronome-tap-pad-right.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="136" Height="209" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Image x:Name="MetronomeWindowHighlight" Height="105" Margin="238.5,18,231.5,0" Source="Images\pad-metronome-window-overlay.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Image x:Name="MetronomeBottomBackground" Margin="3,208,-3,362" Source="Images\pad-metronome-section-bottom-bg.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <my:MetronomeLargeNumericDisplay HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="459,120,0,0" x:Name="NumericDisplay" VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="999" Width="122.25" />
    <Image Height="78" Margin="448,110.5,436,0" Source="Images\pad-metronome-start-button-overlay.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"
           x:Name="DisplayOverlay" MouseDown="DisplayOverlay_MouseDown" />
    <RepeatButton x:Name="ButtonDecrement" Content="" BorderThickness="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="252,110.5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Height="100" Background="{DynamicResource ImageBrush_Decrement}" Style="{DynamicResource RepeatButtonStyle_noflash}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ImageBrush_Decrement}" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Click="ButtonDecrement_Click"></RepeatButton>
    <RepeatButton Content="" BorderThickness="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="631,110.5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Height="100" Background="{DynamicResource ImageBrush_Increment}" Style="{DynamicResource RepeatButtonStyle_noflash}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ImageBrush_Decrement}" Name="ButtonIncrement" Click="ButtonIncrement_Click" />
</Grid>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much messing around with new projects and much simplified code I asked the question slightly differently in another thread and someone posted working code.

on investigation that reason my animation was not working was that I had provided a duration to the animation but not the storyboard itself !! doh.

full answer here (which is one of the fullest answers I have received on this topic)

[How do I create a rotate animation on an image object using c# code only (inside a WPF window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073573/how-do-i-create-a-rotate-animation-on-an-image-object-using-c-sharp-code-only-i)

Lucas, thanks to you for your patience and assistance on this question.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted seems to be ok, however, the path refers to an *existing* element, so make sure you've included appropriate nodes in xaml, where `Arm` control is defined.

Let's say `Arm` is a `Rectangle` control. Your xaml should then look more or less like this:

```
...
<Rectangle x:Name="Arm" Fill="Aqua" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
...
```

`Arm` can be another type of control, but the important thing is that `RenderTransform`, `TransformGroup` and `RotateTransform` nodes are defined, so animation has some existing elements to change as specified in the `PropertyPath` in your code.

Comment: I checked the XAML and it has that transform node defined (now included in the post above for reference is the complete XAML).  still the code and XAML compile but the animation does not run (also added a breakpoint in the code and witnessed it fire and hit the event ok.

Comment: I've copied your code in c# (before you updated your post), added it to sample xaml and it worked. I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but you put the animation creating board in a routed event, and checked that it fires inside your control, am I right? Right now I don't have time to do it, but I'll try to find what the issue is later.

Comment: as it stands right now, the XAML is exactly as posted above and the code is in a function in a  C# module triggered by the mousedown of the window highlight.  the function is firing ok and i can step through the code but at the end the animation is not running....

Comment: the only other point of note is that the whole thing is part of a user control but that shouldnt matter...

Comment: So...is the code in code-behind is in the code of the control or is it used somewhere else (I can see you have access to `Arm` image, but you might get it available outside the cotrol and reference it, so I ask just to make sure).

Comment: I haven't downloaded your code, but I've put the xaml in a `UserControl` and if you invoke this code there is should work correctly. That's why I was asking where you put the c# code.

Comment: so the XAML is in a user control and the code is in the cs fie behind it, the code is executing but the animation not showing (the user control is hosted in a winforms form) ... could you post your project files somewhere for me ? this has driven me nuts!!

Comment: Windows form? I suppose you meant WPF window ;). Try to move this c# code to another event (calling it directly within button click in the user control) just to check if it works for you in that case.

Comment: no i did mean winform ... its a WPF user control that is hosted inside a winform ... too tired tonight to try again, will start from scratch with a basic anim tomorrow.... irritation is that originally i was doing this as a stright transofrm without a story board and it was working fine .... but, i needed to link two animations together so started the story board route...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12651/discussion-between-daniel-gwalter-and-lucas)