# How do I create a rotate animation on an image object using c# code only (inside a WPF window)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, rotation

I have a couple of open questions relating to the same sort of thing,

I am quite new to WPF but experienced with C# and Winforms.

I have looked around on the interweb for a working example but have yet to find one that works.

What I want to achieve is in a C# function create the following

- create an image (image 1)
- create an image (image 2)
- put the images on the window side by side
- create a storyboard
- animate the rotate property of image1 from 0 to 360 (animation1)
- animate the opacity property of image 2 from full to invisible (animation2)
- the storyboard should run for ten seconds with animation 1 starting
  at 0 seconds and animation 2 starting at 5 seconds

apologies for the explicit request for code, but, I have looked, and tried, my previous question had full code that executed but no animation showed (link below)

[how to create a storyboard and rotating an image in wpf using c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057127/how-to-create-a-storyboard-and-rotating-an-image-in-wpf-using-c-code/11058289#11058289)

thanks in advance

Dan.

Comment: Do you really need it all in C# code? parts of this (in particular creating the image and putting them on the window) are just a lot more straightforward in XAML.

Comment: true, the image and the location can be in XAML but the storyboard and the animation must be in c#

Comment: OK, i went ahead and did it all XAML and then all C#. You can mix and match as needed :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136664/how-to-rotate-grid-with-storyboard-in-wpf-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is a working XAML versionn of your question followed by the identical thing in C#. May not be exactly what you were after, but it should illustrate it.

XAML version:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" Duration="00:00:10.000">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateImage" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                             From="0" To="360" BeginTime="00:00:05.000" Duration="00:00:05.000" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OpacityImage" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                             From="1" To="0" Duration="00:00:10.000" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="RotateImage" Stretch="Uniform" Source="Chrysanthemum.jpg">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="OpacityImage" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Uniform" Source="Desert.jpg" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Start">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And C# version:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Image rotateImage = new Image()
        {
            Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Chrysanthemum.jpg")),
            RenderTransform = new RotateTransform()
        };
        Image opacityImage = new Image()
        {
            Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Desert.jpg"))
        };

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rotateImage);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(opacityImage);

        Grid.SetColumn(opacityImage, 1);

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0));
        DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0,
            To = 360,
            Duration = storyboard.Duration
        };
        DoubleAnimation opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 1.0,
            To = 0.0,
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0),
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(rotateAnimation, rotateImage);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, opacityImage);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));

        storyboard.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);
        storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);

        Resources.Add("Storyboard", storyboard);

        Button button = new Button()
        {
            Content = "Begin"
        };
        button.Click += button_Click;

        Grid.SetRow(button, 1);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(button, 2);

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(button);
    }

    void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Storyboard)Resources["Storyboard"]).Begin();
    }
```

Comment: This is great - one question, how to set the centre point of the rotation to the centre of the image (I am using a Path not an image).

Comment: @Duncan, try setting the RenderTransformOrigin to (0.5,0.5).

Answer (score 2):

Animation is work as follows.

1-The program creates a timer.

2-The program checks the timer at set intervals to see how much time has elapsed.

3-Each time the program checks the timer, it computes the current opacity value for the rectangle based on how much time has elapsed.

4-The program then updates the rectangle with the new value and redraws it.

Following is the Code which create Rectangle and animate it.

```
<Window x:Class="Animation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Animated Rectangle" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <Image Name="MyImage" Source="e:\a.jpg" Width="100" Margin="50" ></Image>
        <Rectangle
            Name="MyRectangle"
            Width="100" 
            Height="100"
            Fill="Blue">

            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <!-- Animates the rectangle's opacity. -->
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="MyImage" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:3" 
                                AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```