# Create Rotation Interactive Control in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, user-controls, ribbon

How can we Create interact Rotation Control in Visual Studio?

I see one control which Visual Studio used "Render Transform" Property , marked in attached screen shot.

[image]

May be we'll create through UserControl, but i'm not sure how to create. So please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate any control you like.

[How do I create a rotate animation on an image object using c# code only (inside a WPF window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073573/how-do-i-create-a-rotate-animation-on-an-image-object-using-c-sharp-code-only-i)

This link gives you an example with an Image and a Button.
The button is using a Storyboard that animated the rotation of the image.

Comment: Thanks for Quick reply @Zarkos and I'm sorry i'm not aware of 'LayoutRoot' control. In short i google it but not found which library it's from.  Is 'LayoutRoot' is Silver-light Component?

Comment: @satish_srg I don't really have an Idea where he got the LayoutRoot from. Just name your Grid LayoutRoot and it would be Oké.
 <Grid Name="LayoutRoot"> (Or give your grid a diffrent name, and change LayoutRoot in code behind to something else).

But Add your Control in WPF and than just use it, only add them in code when necessary.

Comment: I just test this and it seems rotating an object when user press the Button. But What i want is Interactive control for Rotation.

Comment: What do u mean with interactive? When does it need to rotate?

Comment: I'm creating 3D application through WPF user controls. So i found Slider which is used  moving and resizing object. But i didn't find  a control which is used to Rotate an selected object.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/15/wpf-image-viewer-part-7-rotating-the-image-with-a.aspx
 This gives a binding to the slider. You could also use the Eventhandler from a slider & than check which item is selected and perform a rotation for the sliders value?

Comment: Thanks @Zarkos for patience , it's good article and may help to me. But i still not satisfy , i'm looking for UI Control. Slider usefull for moving , change values and etc. For rotation it is not good UI control in my case. So that i want to Create new UI control look like "RenderTransform" control in Visual Studio. I worry about UI control only not Coding.

Comment: @satish_srg Just type: circular wpf slider   In google and this will give you helpfull stuff.