# How to rotate grid with Storyboard in wpf c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to rotate simple grid with storyboard in c# code in wpf
my xaml code is

```
<Window x:Class="rotate_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:rotate_test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Name="my_grid">
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

that have grid and one button in it
in onclick event for button I use

```
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        From = 0,
        To = 360,
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
};
    Storyboard.SetTarget(rotateAnimation, my_grid);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));

    storyboard.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);
    storyboard.Begin();
```

but it dose not work
what is my problem?
how can I set Acceleration for animation?
thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the Grid's `RenderTransform` before you can animate it.

```
<Grid Name="my_grid">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

You could also directly animate the `RotateTransform` without a Storyboard.

Just give it a Name

```
<RotateTransform x:Name="transform" />
```

and animate it in code behind like

```
transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateAnimation);
```

---

Besides that, DoubleAnimation has several properties that control acceleration and deceleration, like `AccelerationRatio`, `DecelerationRatio` and `EasingFunction`.

Comment: are you khnow how can I set Acceleration  for it  ?

Comment: Take a look at the online documentation of the properties that I mention in the answer. What you probably want is to set the EasingFunction. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308751(v=vs.100).aspx